# How can I apply regression modeling to analyze the characteristics of Extreme Programming and the Rational Unified Process?

Tags: quality, development-methodologies, extreme-programming, rational-unified-process

I have been given task that has a case study developed by Extreme Programming (XP) and the Rational Unified Process (RUP). I was asked to apply regression models and take some dependent variables and some independent variables in order to compare both XP and RUP. Even though I have been searching, I have not been able to identify dependent and independent variables could be used in software quality testing?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression